# Why doesn't my WHERE clause recognize field as date, even after having converted this field from int to date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, where-clause

I have made the following SELECT statement in SQL Server, which gives me the error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

```
SELECT Id, CAST(CAST(CalendarDate as varchar(10)) as date)
FROM dbo.Sales
WHERE CalendarDate BETWEEN dateadd(month,-6, GETDATE()) AND (GETDATE())
```

`Id` = unique identifier

`CalendarDate` = `int`, which I need to convert to date.

What am I doing wrong?

I wish to find all dates between todays date and 6 months back, however I get the mentioned error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `int` and `date`/`datetime` are two very different types. What conversion would you like it to do?

Comment: Yes. Both the Data types you are trying to compare is different and not compatible. What kind of data you have in **CalendarDate** column ?

Comment: I wish to go from int to date, as I wrote. I also tried to cast as datetime. Still does not work. In CalendarDate column I have data such as "20200821" as an int. This is basically yyyymmdd.

Comment: Just try **WHERE msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(CalendarDate,0) BWTEEEN .....**

Comment: The rules for [data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) show that if you combine an `int` and a `datetime` in an expression then the `int` is converted to a `datetime`. The bad news is that `20200821` doesn't mean what you want it to: `select Cast( 0 as DateTime ) as BaseDate, Cast( 1 as DateTime ) as OneDayLater;`. You'll need to pick your `int` part and reassemble it, e.g. with [`DateFromParts`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert date borders in the WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT Id, CAST(CAST(CalendarDate as varchar(10)) as date)
FROM dbo.Sales
WHERE CalendarDate BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8),dateadd(month,-6, GETDATE()),112)  AS INT) and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) AS INT)
```

Comment: Answer found, but not that SQLServerBuddy's approach for using "WHERE msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(CalendarDate,0) BWTEEEN ..." also works.

Comment: By modifying column's value you'll lose ability to use index on that column. Also, it implies more calculations - more CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Where clause is evaluated before the select clause, thus, the converted field isn't recognized cause it does not exists yet.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement , the order the query is evaluate is the following :

> **Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement**     The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a
> SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in
> one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps. For
> example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the tables or
> views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their columns are
> made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely, because the SELECT
> clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in
> that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they
> can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause.
> The actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the
> query processor and the order may vary from this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP